# PHP HTML Javascript design issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm hoping someone can help me with my design issue.  I have index.php:

which contains a javascript piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/getData.php', function(data) {

    foo...
```

index.php also contains a form that updates the screen:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="update" /></p>
```

Now my problem is I need to pass some variables to getData.php to update the screen.  getData works fine with the static info, but based upon the choices on the form, the data will change.

What's the best way for me to pass variables?

Or am I designing this incorrectly?

Thanks

---

My updated javascript looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$.getJSON('http://localhost/getData.php', {
group_value: $('#group_id option:selected').val(),
updatedb_value: $('#update_db_id').val() 
}, function(data) {
```

Then my form looks like this:

```
<form id="myform" action="index.php" method="post" />
<select id="group_id" name="group">
<option value="0">Atlanta</option>
<option value="1">Chicago</option>
<option value="2">Los Angeles</option>
<option value="3">New York</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Update" />
<input type="checkbox" id="update_db_id" name="update_db" value="1" />Update DB?<br />
</form>
```

No matter what I select or check, When ever I click the update button, the JS console shows that

```
GET http://localhost/getData.php?group_value=0&updatedb_value=1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest changing `http://localhost/getData.php` to simply `/getData.php` - localhost won't work if you deployed this as-is to a real server. That, and unless you're using JSONP, all your URLs should be relative to the root domain anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but same result.  No matter what I select on the form, I get the following results: `GET http://localhost/getData.php?group_value=0&updatedb_value=1`.

Comment: Does anyone have any other suggestions?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$(input_selector).val()` to get the value of a form input, and you can pass it to getJSON as an object, like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/getData.php', {
    some_value: $(some_input).val(),
    other_value: $(other_input).val()
}, function(data) { ... });
```

You can also use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to pass all the form data:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/getData.php', $(form_selector).serialize(), function(data) { ... });
```

Comment: How would I access this from getData.php which is an all php script?

Comment: @Peaceful_Warrior, the data will be available in the `$_GET` variable. See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: I can't get this to work.  I did this `$.getJSON('http://localhost/getData.php', $('#myform').serialize(), function(data) { ... });` then this `<form id="myform" action="index.php" method="post" />
<input type="submit" name="action" value="update" />`  Then, when I go to getData.php & do this `if (isset($_GET["action"])) { do stuff }` nothing happens.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look into the value of `$('#myform').serialize()` in your js console. It's possible serialize doesn't take into account the value of the submit button, I'm not sure. If it doesn't, you'll have to pass that in manually using the first method I posted.

Comment: Ben this isn't working.  I'm going to put the full code of what I have & see if you can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Peaceful_Warrior, if you have more info click "edit" under your question and just add it there. You shouldn't post an answer with new information.

Comment: @Peaceful_Warrior, with respect to your actual problem, select boxes work differently than regular form inputs because they are composed of many elements. You instead have to get the value of the specific selected element. You can do that like this: `$('#group_id option:selected').val();`

Comment: Ok.  I deleted the answer & updated the OP.  So, I had tried that earlier with the `option:selected` & it didn't work.  Just copied & pasted your code to make sure there were not typo's & removed the ";" & it still doesn't work.  Same thing happens with `$('#myform').serialize()` except it only returns the "group" parameter.  Is there something I'm missing because I've read the api.jquery.com & searched on the net, but can't get this code to work.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Look very closely at this line:

```
<form id="myform" action="index.php" method="post" />
```

Oops. You self-closed your form. That may be causing issues with how the input/select elements update. Try changing it to:

```
<form id="myform" action="index.php" method="post">
```

You also don't actually need the complex selector on the select element. This will also get you the selected value:

```
$('#group_id').val()
```

Comment: Thanks, I've taken all the suggestions you guys have provided & still can't seem to get it to work.  I still get `GET http://localhost/getData.php?group_value=0&updatedb_value=1
` in JS Console.